# Aggregate n DataFrames into a single DataFrame - element-wise

Tags: python, pandas, design-patterns

What is the pythonic way to generate a pandas DataFrame using an aggregation function to combine several other DataFrames? (DataFrames are all of the same shape with same headers.)

Aggregation functions I might be interested in are mean, minimum, maximum and user defined functions taking two operands.

For example, this is the way I might generate a DataFrame (`max`) which has the maximum element from four other DataFrames (`df1,df2,df3,df4`). This is hardly a pattern (idiom) that I can apply in all situations and to calculate the mean would look quite different.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3], 'b': [3,9,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [6,2,7], 'b': [3,4,5]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [6,2,11], 'b': [3,4,5]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [6,2,7], 'b': [3,12,5]})
print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)
print(df4)

max1 = df1.where(df1 > df2, df2)
max2 = df3.where(df3 > df4, df4)
max = max1.where(max1 > max2, max2)
print(max)
```

An example of a user defined function taking two operands which I will also want to apply, is the following which is essentially the same as max in this example but will be something more complicated in practice

```
def myagg(a, b):
    return a > b
```

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate them all with `pd.concat` and then `groupby` to find `max`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], 1).groupby(level=0, axis=1).max()

    a   b
0   6   3
1   2  12
2  11   5
```

Compare this to your method which also returns:

```
max

    a   b
0   6   3
1   2  12
2  11   5
```

Note that the column names across every dataframe would have to be the same for this (as well as your current method) to work.

---

As piR mentioned, the `describe` function performs some general aggregations for you:

```
lodf = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

pd.concat(lodf, keys=range(len(lodf))) \
  .groupby(level=1).describe().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)

    25%       50%       75%       count        max        mean        min  \
      a    b    a    b    a     b     a    b     a     b     a     b    a   
0  4.75  3.0  6.0  3.0  6.0  3.00   4.0  4.0   6.0   3.0  4.75  3.00  1.0   
1  2.00  4.0  2.0  6.5  2.0  9.75   4.0  4.0   2.0  12.0  2.00  7.25  2.0   
2  6.00  5.0  7.0  5.0  8.0  5.00   4.0  4.0  11.0   5.0  7.00  5.00  3.0   

             std            
     b         a         b  
0  3.0  2.500000  0.000000  
1  4.0  0.000000  3.947573  
2  5.0  3.265986  0.000000
```

Comment: or use `describe` instead of `max`

Comment: Thank you. How do I apply my own user defined function instead of max() ?

Comment: @T33C You can use the `groupby.apply` function, and pass your custom function to it.

Comment: Can't get `apply` to work with my example udf as a replacement for max, def myagg(a, b):
    return a > b

Comment: @T33C I'm assuming your actual function does something other than find the max. `apply` will pass the entire sub-dataframe to your function.  So you will need to re-write your function to handle that. Do `.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: print(x))` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I really like the use of concat and groupby which is much clearer and I hope to understand how to get the apply part to work with a function expecting two simple values. I will try again tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @T33C let me know if your query was not solved. Edit your question with a [mcve] that captures the essence of your problem. Thanks.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thanks for your help. My question is not 100% answered because I am not sure how to use the myagg function. The end note in the answer about `describe` is not really answering my question.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ myagg, is defined at the bottom of my question. (As an example of a user defined function taking two operands.) The example is greater than, but it could be anything.

Comment: @T33C What I meant to say is what do you want to pass to `myagg` as params?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ For each element of the input arrays I want to select the element which causes myagg to return true when given as the first parameter against all other elements given - in turn - as the second parameter. In my example definition of myagg this would return the maximum element.

Comment: @T33C I understood. Unfortunately, `agg` is not meant to work that way. It works on a single column at a time. You seem to want some sort of functional programming `reduce` functionality, that pandas doesn't support.